# Find emails in the same table that having %40 in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns - id, email

What query can I run to show only single emails having %40 ?

e.g. my table is

```
id  email
-------------
1   stevemartin140%40gmail.com

2   stevemartin141%40gmail.com

3   stevemartin140@gmail.com

4   stevemartin141@gmail.com

5   stevemartin148%40gmail.com

6   andymartin%40ymail.com
```

So result will be:

```
id  email
-------------
5   stevemartin148%40gmail.com

6   andymartin%40ymail.com
```

i would like to find out & replace those emails with @

so my final output will be:

```
id  email
-------------
1   stevemartin140%40gmail.com

2   stevemartin141%40gmail.com

3   stevemartin140@gmail.com

4   stevemartin141@gmail.com

5   stevemartin148@gmail.com

6   andymartin@ymail.com
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the must performance one but to find duplicate...

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY REPLACE(email, '%40', '@') HAVING COUNT(*) < 2 AND email LIKE '%\%40%';
```

MySQL compliant

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6808c/3/0

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replace them, then:

```
UPDATE t SET email=REPLACE(email, '%40', '@')
```

-in MySQL.

Comment: If downvote, please, comment so I will know how to improve my answer & knowledge

Comment: That's just one little problem. If the `VARCHAR` have another **%40**, it will be replaced too. But I don't think you can use % on an email address.

Comment: If it has, than in common case you can not determine which **%40** should be replaced. So - yes, you should rely on the fact, that valid email should not have more than 1 occurrence or this symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `like '%\%40%'` in your where condition to escape the wildcard, like this:

```
select * from t1 where email like '%\%40%';
```

here is the [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdde1/4)